# How to post data to firebase using PHP?

Tags: php, curl, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Laravel framework and integrated with Firebase database. I try to post data as follows to Firebase but its not working.

```
    $url = "https://test.firebaseio.com/test_api/types.json";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                               
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id=6");
    $jsonResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

I do not where is the problem. And also I have tried to do this using postman and it says following error. `"error": "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value. Perhaps you're using invalid characters in your key names."` How I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following one

```
    $data = '{"id": "6"}';

    $url = "https://test.firebaseio.com/test_api/types.json";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                               
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain'));
    $jsonResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_errno($ch))
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

Firebase accept json object and you have to post `$data` as json object. And you can use `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `Content-Type: text/plain`

Answer (score 1):

id=6 is not a valid JSON. {"id":6} is probably what you meant.

try

```
$json='{"id":6}';
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_POST=>1,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json)
),
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$json
));
```

EDIT: or if the site accepts normal POST multipart/form-data / application/x-www-form-urlencoded encodings, you probably want, for multipart/form-data encoding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('id'=>6));
```

for application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('id'=>6)));
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Problem is the id=6 is not a valid JSON.