# How to use socket in android to get JSON response from REST Api to inflate recyclerview dynamically?

Tags: android, laravel, sockets, android-recyclerview, socket.io

I am developing an android app for making a forum for communication between a particular group of user.I am using PHP Laravel as my backend and communication via API calls.
I have used REST API calls to post data to my server and receive the conversations posted and inflated it using recyclerview.
Everything is working fine but what I want is **to update the recyclerview data dynamically when the database is updated with new data so that the user gets to see the new data without refreshing the page.**
Basically I do not want to call the API every time to inflate the recyclerview.


While browsing I got some hint to use Socket as **because we can keep the connection open unlike in HTTP REST API calls which terminates after the response**.
But I don't know how to combine Socket with REST API calls .

Comment: search for tutorials in youtube or go for udemy, coursera.

Comment: @SAM I am going through as many sources as  I can . But please let me know whether using Socket is good idea or not .

Comment: I personally would not use sockets unless I was connecting to a non-public network (eg. company internal server or home server). You could use firebase.

Comment: @Barns I know it can be done using firebase but my complete database is on phpmysql server and backend in Laravel,and I am fetching data using API calls .So shifting the database to Firebase will not work for me .

Comment: No need to get rid of the database you have. Just let firebase manage the update part.

Comment: @Barns Ok thanks will try to implement it .

Comment: @Barns It worked ,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what I wanted by using Firebase and not by Socket.

I followed these steps.

1. I posted the data from Laravel Backend to Firebase Database like the answer in *[How to post data to firebase using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032050/how-to-post-data-to-firebase-using-php)*  .
2. I fetched that data in my android app using this set of code

   ```
   progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
   showDialog();
   databaseReference.child("root_id").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
    {
           forumlist.clear();               
           int l = (int) dataSnapshot.child(msgid).getChildrenCount();               
           for(DataSnapshot uniqueKeySnapshot : dataSnapshot.child(msgid).getChildren()){
              ForumSubData subData = uniqueKeySnapshot.getValue(ForumSubData.class);
               forumlist.add(subData);
           }
               recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
               mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
           hideDialog();
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           hideDialog();
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant in my suggestion. I like the way you implemented Firebase in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever data in db change you need to transmit it via socket and when you receive you need to call service again to update recyclerview. Use socket.io and node.js for this.

Visit following links:

https://socket.io/

https://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

https://socket.io/docs/server-api/

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io

https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket-io-server

These links have information,documentation and implementation with examples from setting server to getting response on android.

Comment: I used Firebase instead of Socket ,though your information helped me get a better idea about Socket.